# Using Selenium (Webdriver) to test Merge

Tags: selenium, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to verify restricted fields aren't merged using the OOB merge. I get to the merge window, but can't figure out how to get selenium to click the "**OK**" button on the dialog

I've confirmed in the html that the element is the `InlineDialog_Iframe`, and I've tried `xrmBrowser.Dialog.ClickCommand()`, as well as `SwitchtTo()` etc, nothing seems to work.

```
//select both records
xrmBrowser.Grid.SelectRecord(0);
xrmBrowser.Grid.SelectRecord(1);
//click Merge
xrmBrowser.CommandBar.ClickCommand("Merge");
//click Okay ----what goes here?----
```

Comment: Show us the code with `switch` and then `click`. Add HTML source

Comment: I don't know anything about Dynamics but it seems to me like it may be one of a couple situations... a JS alert box or a dialog that uses an IFRAME. If it's a JS alert, if you right-click on it you shouldn't get a context menu. If this is the case look for a class called Alert or something similar... that's what it's called in regular Selenium, (see [Alert](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html)).

Comment: If that's not it, you referenced an element in the `InlineDialog_Iframe`. In regular Selenium you have to switch driver context into an IFRAME (see [switchTo()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--)), then you can access the elements inside the IFRAME. You can find code on SO or tutorials on the web and try to translate them or find equivalents in Dynamics.